# Laravel DB query with warning message

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

All I want is to have an if statement that exceeds number of absences and show the message.

Here's the SQL query

```
public function countAbsent()
    {

        $absent = Attendances::select(DB::raw('count(status)'))
                 ->where('student_id', '=',  Auth::user()->id)
                 ->where('status', '=', 'absent')
                 ->where('section_name', 'like', Input::get('section_name'))
                 ->where('subject_code', 'like', Input::get('subject_code'))
                 ->count();

        return View::make('student.view_absent')
                 ->with('absent', $absent);


    }
```

Comment: So what is the warning message?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass another variable to view:

```
public function countAbsent()
{

    $absent = Attendances::select(DB::raw('count(status)'))
             ->where('student_id', '=',  Auth::user()->id)
             ->where('status', '=', 'absent')
             ->where('section_name', 'like', Input::get('section_name'))
             ->where('subject_code', 'like', Input::get('subject_code'))
             ->count();

    $absent_message = 'Students are not exceeding the absence threshold';

    $threshold = 10; //whatever you like

    if ($absent > $threshold)
    {
        $absent_message = 'Students are exceeding the absence threshold';
    }

    return View::make('student.view_absent')
             ->with('absent', $absent)
             ->with('absent_message', $absent_message);


}
```

And echo the `$absent_message` in the View `student.view_absent`.